# Solving Error: size mismatch, m1: [30 x 2], m2: [30 x 2]

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, pytorch

I am getting the below error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 122, in <module>
    agent = Agent(lr=0.001, input_dims=env.observation_space.shape, n_actions=env.action_space.n)

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.Q = LinearDQN(self.lr, self.n_actions, self.input_dims)

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.fc1 = T.flatten(nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128))

TypeError: flatten(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Linear


runfile('C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Bitcoin/Q_Learning/DQN_NEW_Original.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Bitcoin/Q_Learning')
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 37
    actions = self.fc2(layer1)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


runfile('C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Bitcoin/Q_Learning/DQN_NEW_Original.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Bitcoin/Q_Learning')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 133, in <module>
    agent.learn(obs, action, reward, obs_)

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 80, in learn
    q_pred = self.Q.forward(states)[actions]

  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Bitcoin\Q_Learning\DQN_NEW_Original.py", line 36, in forward
    layer1 = F.relu(T.flatten(self.fc1(state)))

  File "C:\Users\Sam\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Sam\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 87, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

  File "C:\Users\Sam\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1610, in linear
    ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [30 x 2], m2: [30 x 2] at C:/w/b/windows/pytorch/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:283
```

The error is something to do with the size of my Tensors - I have tried permuting the input data but that returns a new error.

Also worth noting that when the error  m1: [30 x 2] increases by the factor of my batch size, when I increase batch size above 1.

```
 super(LinearDQN, self).__init__()
 self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128)
 self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions)
```

The input dims are [30,2] and n_actions is 2.

Also note that the error ‘m1: [30 x 2]’ increases in multiples of my batch size (no idea why).

Cheers all,

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in the messages you showed. Maybe you tried running your code multiple times, commenting out or changing the lines causing errors to see if it worked? Anyway, here are my guesses:

- `TypeError: flatten(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Linear`: this is because at line 22 of file `DQN_NEW_Original.py` you typed `self.fc1 = T.flatten(nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128))` and `flatten` is just an operation, not a Pytorch module, which means that it receives tensors as parameters, not blocks (which is what `Linear` is). `flatten` is used in the `forward` method, not in the constructor.
- `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Without more context, I am not sure what the cause for this might be.
- `RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [30 x 2], m2: [30 x 2]...`: this is because you declared `fc1` as  `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128)` and `input_dims` being `[30, 2]`, which would lead to the invocation `nn.Linear(30, 2, 128)`. However, if you take a look of [`Linear`'s documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), you will see that it only receives 2 arguments (not 3, like you used): input features and output features. Input features should be the last dimension of the input tensor.

Comment: Thanks a lot - apologies for adding the other error codes in at the start, I copied too much from the console. I'm still struggling to solve the RuntimeError, should I be using a different type of layer for the input?

Comment: No. The problem is how you create the `Linear`. In order to fix it you should think about what is the meaning of each dimension in the input: what do the 30 and the 2 refer to? Is 2 the size of the state vector and 30 the batch size?

Comment: The size of the observation space is (30, 2) and the batch size is 32 - I think I could get it to work by changing the observation space into just (30,) but that may cause problems later.

I have got it to work like this 

        `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2,len(input_dims))
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(n_actions, 30) `

But that returns another error and I'm not sure if it solves the issue.

Comment: The point is that the linear layer will only affect the dimensionality of the last dimension of the input. If the observation space is `(30, 2)`, and the output dimensionality should be `(2,)`, then at some point you should flatten the extra dimension, e.g. having `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(60, 128)` and then having `state.view(-1, 60)` before using `self.fc1`.

Comment: If the answer is considered correct, please mark it with the tick button. Otherwise, please let me know any doubts you have.